# Python: Appending items to lists by iterating through list of lists

Tags: python

I'm a Python newbie crossing over from C. I'm basically trying implement logic equivalent to an array of array pointers in C.

I want to append one item to the ends of a bunch of lists by iterating over a list of these lists. I have the following code:

```
data = [10, 20, 30]
list1 = list2 = list3 = list()
lists = [list1, list2, list3]

for i in range(len(data)):
    lists[i].append(data[i])

for lst in lists:
    print lst
```

It's result, however, is:

```
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 20, 30]
[10, 20, 30]
```

instead of:

```
[10]
[20]
[30]
```

I can't explain why this code fails to produce the desired output, and is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: 1 loop is not enough for the pblm ithink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only create one list

```
list1 = list2 = list3 = list()
```

this line creates an empty list, assigns its reference to `list3`, assigns **reference** to `list3` to `list2` and to `list1`, as a result these refer to **the same object**. So when you add your values, you add them to all of your "lists".

This will work just fine

```
data = [10, 20, 30]
lists = [[], [], []]

for i in range(len(data)):
    lists[i].append(data[i])

for lst in lists:
    print lst
```

But the simplest way would be to do just

```
data = [10, 20, 30]
lists = [ [x] for x in data ]
```

Comment: The list comprehension is indeed simplest, but it's also notable that we can express the loop as `for i,v in enumerate(data): lists[i].append(v)`, or `for lst,value in zip(lists,data): lst.append(value)`. Needlessly using indices is a bit of a C-ism.