# Python uncaught List variable's behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7

Can anyone please explain the output i am getting. As the first time the variable `lists` is blank but when `data[i]` i.e `10` appended to the `lists[i]` it becomes

```
List:  [[10], [10, [10]]
```

I dont know how come this long list comes in. I am new to python struck to trace its behavior. Here is the code

```
data = [10, 20, 30]
list1 = list2 = list3 = list()
lists = [list1, list2, list3]

for i in range(len(data)):
  lists[i].append(data[i])
  print '-------------------'
  print 'at %s' %(i)
  print '  List:  %s' % (lists)
  print '  Data: %s' %  (data[i])
```

And response

```
-------------------
at 0
 List:  [[10], [10], [10]]
 Data: 10
-------------------
at 1
List:  [[10, 20], [10, 20], [10, 20]]
Data: 20
-------------------
at 2
List:  [[10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30]]
Data: 30
```

Comment: @lejlot, No its not complete duplicate of the post you mentioned. here i need the explanation explained perfectly in the Post mentioned by Rohit

Comment: It is explained in both questions, while in the one marked by Rohit is actually a bit different, as it also shows how the list multiplication operation treats the references (which is **not the case** here). But it is not really important, either way - it is a duplicate question, and already has a good answers on the site, hope they helped you understand the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

This is **an invalid** question (it contains output of other code then provided), you are probably running the second (after initialization) part multiple times in your interpreter. The output of your code should look like

```
-------------------
at 0
  List:  [[10], [10], [10]]
  Data: 10
-------------------
at 1
  List:  [[10, 20], [10, 20], [10, 20]]
  Data: 20
-------------------
at 2
  List:  [[10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30], [10, 20, 30]]
  Data: 30
```

tested on Python 2.7

The aspect of "multiple additions" has been already answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929746/python-appending-items-to-lists-by-iterating-through-list-of-lists) so I do not duplicate this information.

Comment: Yes you are right, accidentally i did that .. i admit my mistake
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that output is not from the *complete* code you posted. It looks a whole lot like the list you append to (you have only one, though all the names list1, list2, list3 and lists[i] refer to it) has not been created fresh for each run of the loop, which is done by the second and third line of the code you posted.

Comment: Yes, you are right, i have executed this code i dont know how many times to the terminal using ipython because of that got that response but now i have improved its answer

for i in range(len(data)):
   ....:       lists[i].append(data[i])
   ....:       print '-------------------'
   ....:       print 'at %s' %(i)
   ....:       print '  List:  %s' % (lists)
   ....:       print '  Data: %s' %  (data[i])

Comment: Thanks for your hint and now its all cear